# how to prevent dynamic image Cache

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a website where people can upload their own profile pictures. I put the profile picture to my servers root folder with the name of "theirusername.jpg/png" whatever and write into the DB the location of the picture like: "../profile/username.jpg". Now my question is...
After upload I'm opening a resizer box where users can resize their profile pic to make it fit into the profile pic box. I was calling new image dynamically with a php get-url to trigger no cache: "../images/username.jpg?number=randomgeneratednumber". But now it is not working as expected and I don't why nor what to do. I'm looking for a decent answer still.

```
    var frm3 = $('#uploadimg');
frm3.submit(function (evenn) {
    $('#uploadprc').show();
    swing();
    $.ajax({
        type: frm3.attr('method'),
        url: frm3.attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,
        success: function (response) {
            var rand= Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000000);
            var rand2= Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000000);
            $('#centersizer').removeData();
            $('#usercode').load('php/userpanel.php');
            $('#resp').text(response);
            showntf();
            setTimeout(function() {
            if(response == "The file has been uploaded."){
            $('#profpic').css('background-image','url(<? echo $result['profimg']; ?>?mark='+rand+')');
            $('#centersizer').load('../widgets/resizertool.php');
            $('#resizewrapper').show();
            }
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#imageholder').css('background-image','url(<? echo $result['profimg']; ?>?mark='+rand2+')');
            },1200);
        }
    });

    evenn.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're rendering these images as css background. What happens if you render them with regular `<img   />` tags instead? Is some aspect of css optimization defeating your reloading of them?  Look at the network tab in `<F12>` developer tools to see whether your browser is reloading them.

Comment: The idea that im not putting them into img tags is in css im giving background-position according to how user placed it according to resizetool data. X-axis and Y-axis i mean and zoom as well. So user can personalize their profile img to fit it onti the circle of the profile pic. in dev tool nothing appears wrong. it loads the img but the old one it gets not because of browser cache (because browser cache become disabled due to giving it a random number to the en of url) but server cache i belive.